# Setting a list of objects as the Items.Source for a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hi I'm trying to display the properties of a bunch of objects that are stored in a list inside a datagrid.

This is what i have so far:

datagrid:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GlauxSoft.UebungsAufgaben.Projektmanagement.ListenAnsicht"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GlauxSoft.UebungsAufgaben.Projektmanagement"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="850">
<DataGrid Name="dg_listenansicht">



</DataGrid>
```

my attempt to add the list:

```
public partial class ListenAnsicht : UserControl
{
    public ListenAnsicht()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FillListenAnsicht();
    }

    void FillListenAnsicht()
    {

        dg_listenansicht.ItemsSource = MainWindow.termine;

    }
}
```

and finaly my actual list:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static List<Termin> termine = new List<Termin>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ErsteTermine();
    }

    public void ErsteTermine()
    {
        TerminHinzufügen(12, 4, 2, 5, "steve", "project1", new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue));
        TerminHinzufügen(34, 2, 3, 5, "jacob", "project1", new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green));
        TerminHinzufügen(23, 5, 5, 10, "billy", "project2", new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue));
    }

    public static void TerminHinzufügen(int newweek, int newday, int newstart, int newend, string newemployee, string newproject, SolidColorBrush newcolor)
    {
        Termin termin = new Termin()
        {
            week = newweek,
            start = newstart,
            end = newend,
            employee = newemployee,
            project = newproject,
            color = newcolor,
            day = newday
        };
        termine.Add(termin);
    }
```

What this does is just add 3 empty rows to my datagrid.

Comment: Where do you add items to the List<Termin>?

Comment: @mm8 sorry, i was missing a part edited it in

Comment: How is the Termin class defined?

Comment: As a note, you could write `Brushes.Blue` instead of `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `week`, `start`, `end`, etc. of the `Termin` class are defined as public *properties* and not fields:

```
public class Termin
{
    public int week { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int end { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

You can only bind to public properties.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF easiest way to bind data to context is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface into class and use ObservableCollection instead of list.

I don't see from XAML is AutoGenerateColumns poroperty of datagrid set to true.

Also we can't see if TerminHinzufügen class has INotifyPropertyChanged  interface implemented.

Here is link to simple sample of binding collection to control:
https://wpf.2000things.com/2013/05/27/828-listview-and-gridview-data-binding-example/